# Shell script `read` prompt for path not working with spaces / special chars

Tags: bash, shell

I have a shell script that is prompting the user to enter a path:

```
read -e -p "Enter the path to the file: " FILEPATH
eval FILEPATH=$FILEPATH
```

If I enter one like so:

`Enter the path to the file: ~/Desktop/Hello\ My\ Name\ is\ Oliver/`

Then I get the following output (bash in debug mode):

```
Enter the path to the file: ~/Desktop/Hello\ My\ Name\ is\ Oliver/
+ eval 'FILEPATH=~/Desktop/Hello My Name is Oliver/'
++ FILEPATH=/Users/Oliver/Desktop/Hello
++ My Name is Oliver/
```

I also have similar problems when there are special characters in the path.

What can I do to solve this problem?

**Edit:** `eval` corrects aliases like `~` to their proper paths.

Comment: **Do not use `eval` here!** It's terribly dangerous! What if someone enters `a rm *` or `a very_evil_command`? What's the use of `eval` anyway?

Comment: `eval` seems to calculate the path of `~`. If I don't use it, then the shell will attempt to CD to directories with spaces like so: `cd '~/Desktop/Hello My Name is Oliver` – but `~` cannot be resolved when wrapped in quotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just need to expand `~`,, it's safer to do something like

```
FILEPATH=${FILEPATH/\~/$HOME}
```

This will also keep the variable all together.